# What is the fastest way to load a big data set into a GridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a data source with 1.4+ millions rows in it, and growing.

We make the users add filters to cut the called data down, but you are still looking at 43,000+/- to 100,000 +/- rows at a time.

Before any one says, no one can look at that many rows anyway, they are exported to a excel workbook for calculations based on them.

I am loading the result as follows in the GridView from the CSV file that is returned:

```
Object result = URIService.data;
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(result);
DataTable dataTable = csvReader.CreateDataTable(true, true);

If(dataTable != null)
{
    gridView1.BeginUpdate();
    gridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    gridView1.DataBind()
    gridView1.EndUpdate();
}
Else
{
    Return;
}
```

CSVReader is a CSV Parser.

My question is, is this the best and most efficient way to load a large data set to a gridview?

EDIT: Would using a list for the rows or something other than a data table be better?

Comment: are you sure that databinding is slow ? Did you measure performance of that code with Visual Studio profiler ?

Comment: If you're having slow loading times, try something like adding pages like in the link I provide. It may or may not help as I've never tested it before. But it looks fairly simple to implement for you to try. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211551/A-Simple-way-for-Paging-in-DataGridView-in-WinForm

Comment: @Antonio Bakula yes I did, I am looking for any improvement in loading time and on the front end, it is the only point I see I may be able to improve performance.

Comment: Didn't really answer the question. My bad. Yes, the way you're doing it should be fine. DataBinding is about the fastest way I know of. For that many records it won't be super speedy. It's not the CreateDataTable() method that's slowing it down a ton?

Comment: @N4TKD just saying, first obvious thing is DataTable, why don't you bind your grid directly to CSV collection ? And what exacly CVS Parser are you using (try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)

Comment: @AntonioBakula can you give me a example of binding to a CSV direct and yes it is a modified A-Fast-CSV-Reader, the change is adding datatype row to parse. I would need to to be able to add the type to the binding can that be done?

Comment: well I can't for your customized version, but on link below there is a example of binding csv directly to the grid, look at Complex Data-Binding Scenario (Windows Forms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is only one way to load the large data set into grid-view and it is the one you are using right now, but if you want to make the performance better I highly recommend using pagination so you have chunks of data loaded on every page therefore you will decrease the loading time

http://sivanandareddyg.blogspot.com/2011/11/efficient-server-side-paging-with.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125541/Effective-Paging-with-GridView-Control-in-ASP-NET

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx

Comment: Can you give a example, I was wondering about using a data table compared to a list or ??? something else.

Comment: I have links that should help you

Comment: thanks I will look them over, but I am working on a Winform Application and I think you are talking ASP.net.

Comment: can we use ajax for that..?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [buffered renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer)?

Answer (score 0):

in the case of SQL SERVER use SqlBulkCopy class to copy large data with the highest speed