# Biniding data from dataset to gridview taking time

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am having one windows form which is dynamic form,used in many forms.
In this form i have to bind data from dataset to datagridview.But takes 3-4 minutes to bind data from dataset to datagridview.Result from query executed is placed in dataset.And then this dataset is then bind to datagridview as

```
dgSearch.DataSource=ds.tables[0];
```

but this statement takes time to execute.As my dataset has more than 100k rows. How to bind such large amount of data to datagridview?

I have a C# windows application.

Comment: how many records do you have?

Comment: more than 1 lakh rows

Comment: @aliboy - a Lahk is 100K in English number systems.

Comment: @GregoryABeamer I know that, dude.

Comment: Page it or use a 3rd party control that can virtually page it. That is a rediculous amount to load at once though. It's not consumable by a user. Filter first for a better experience.

Answer (score 0):

First, the idea of binding that much data in an application suggests either a) bad architecture or b) bad business requirements. People cannot process 100,000 rows at one time. If this is a report, then the grid is not your best way of handling this.

If you are forced to head this direction, I would consider some form of paging and only show a portion of the "gridded" data at any one time. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16303/DataGrid-Paging-C-Windows-Forms

Heading this direction, you can control the amount of data that is bound at any one time. You can also implement sort on different columns so the user can refine what he or she is looking at. But you will dramatically speed up binding, as you are not binding 100K+ rows at a time.

Comment: It seems this user only ask question, not accept the answers. take a look at his questions' histories. ;)

Comment: Ah. I see. And I was just answering the question you asked without context. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have large amount of records, the best way to show the records is that you have paging in your gridview.

> Effective paging is important for applications that handle large number of records to build scalable applications.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125541/Effective-Paging-with-GridView-Control-in-ASP-NET) is the good article for that. It shows you how to do it on ASP.NET web forms, but when you find out the way of that you can do it on windows forms application.

Also there is another question may help you with that. [What is the fastest way to load a big data set into a GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411266/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-load-a-big-data-set-into-a-gridview) It's for windows forms application. You may read this too for solving your problem.

Hope it helps.